# Get select value of JQuery Chosen from server side?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-chosen

I want to get the select value of Jquery chosen dynamically populated from c# code.

I can populate my select, but the select always return the first item not the real select item. 
Here the declaration of my select

```
 <select id="slDyn" class="chosen-select" runat="server" clientidmode="Static">
     <option>Please choose from above</option>
  </select>
```

Here the code to populate dynamically

```
var $secondChoice = $("#slDyn");
$secondChoice.empty();
$.each(data, function (index, value) {
  $secondChoice.append(' <option value="' + value+ '">' + value+ '</option>');
});
$("#slDyn").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

When I try to get the selected value it's always return "Please choose from above"

I can't find the error or if it's possible to do this like that.

thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use view state to hold selected value. `EnableViewState="true"`

```
<select id="slDyn" class="chosen-select" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" EnableViewState="true">
     <option>Please choose from above</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: It won't work cz simply adding `EnableViewState` property doesn't mean it will start preserving items even if you are binding it on client side.

Comment: any other solution to achieve this task?